# Manually updated tqdm.notebook bar disappears after first inner loop iteration

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, tqdm

I am working on pytorch models in a jupyter notebook and want to train multiple slightly different models in a loop by running a nested loop. In the outer loop, I instantiate the model, optimizer, etc., in the inner loop I iterate through the number of epochs. A simplified version of my code (without the pytorch operations, **runs without problems**) looks like this:

```
import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

n_models = 5
epochs = 1000

progress = tqdm(total=(n_models*epochs))

for i in range(n_models):
    # instantiate model
    # load data
    # set optimizer
    for j in epochs(epochs):
        time.sleep(0.005) # run pytorch model
        progress.set_description(f"Progessing model: {i+1}, epoch: {j+1}")
        progress.update(1)
        progress.refresh()

progress.close()
```

The `tqdm` bar is showing correctly for the first 1000 steps, however the problem arises at the end of the first iteration/start of the second. The block of code keeps running, but the `tqdm` bar just disappears without raising any errors or warnings. What could be causing the problem and how do I resolve it?